# Create application setting in Settings app

Tags: iphone, settings

I am very new to iPhone programming and I was wondering how could I create a separate section for my application in the Settings.app? Like what the Facebook or BeejiveIM or JellyCar apps do. Would I have to declare this dynamically, or could I use Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accomplish this by creating a Settings.bundle in your project.  Inside the Settings.bundle, you define the settings (names, types, defaults, etc) you are interested in.  When the app is installed, the OS will handle creating the pages in the Settings app for you.

The process is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5).

Comment: link's not working anymore, but I think you meant this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5

Answer (score 2):

There's the InAppSettingsKit: http://github.com/steipete/InAppSettings

Aiming to match the settings from the settings with the ones in your app.

Comment: But you still need to follow the process of highlycaffeinated answer.